# What is the difference between "Generating reports via build.xml" and "Generating via pom.xml"?

Tags: xslt, ant, testng, pom.xml

Earlier I was using build.xml (ant) to run my test cases but now I use pom.xml (maven) to run the test cases.
When I had ant I was able to get testng-xslt reports but after reading many blogs and tutorials I couldnt generate via pom. I wanted to investigate that what is the difference and I saw that I had saxon.jar in my class path but it was missing in pom.xml so I added a dependency. Second thing that I notice that I haven't specified the .xml path in pom.xml(I dont know where to add it in pom). 
I am giving both pom.xml and build.xml here, please take a look on both and let me know what I have missed to generate testng-xslt reports via pom.xml but it was present in build.xml and how I can fix that.
**build.xml**

```
    <target name="testng-xslt-report">
            <delete dir="${basedir}/testng-xslt">
            </delete>
            <mkdir dir="${basedir}/testng-xslt">
            </mkdir>
            <xslt in="${basedir}/test-output/testng-results.xml" style="${basedir}/testng-results.xsl" out="${basedir}/testng-xslt/index.html">
                <param expression="${basedir}/testng-xslt/" name="testNgXslt.outputDir" />

                <param expression="true" name="testNgXslt.sortTestCaseLinks" />

                <param expression="FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS" name="testNgXslt.testDetailsFilter" />

                <param expression="true" name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals" />

                <classpath location="D:\automation\windowsproject\zookeeper\lib\saxon-8.7.jar">
                </classpath>
            </xslt>
    </target>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resource</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>
                            C:/Users/windowspc/workspace/windows-project/Chrome.xml
                        </suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <testFailureIgnore>
                        true
                    </testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>

                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.testng.xslt</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng-xslt-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDir>C:/Users/windowspc/workspace/windows-project/target/testng-xslt-report</outputDir>
                    <showRuntimeTotals>true</showRuntimeTotals>
                    <sortTestCaseLinks>true</sortTestCaseLinks>
                    <testDetailsFilter>FAIL,PASS,SKIP,CONF</testDetailsFilter>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>testng-xslt-plugin</id>
            <url>http://uhftopic.com/maven/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    ...
    ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
            <artifactId>saxon</artifactId>
            <version>8.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a new version of this plugin. It's groupId/artifactId as changed. Here is what you can use:

```
<groupId>org.reportyng</groupId>
<artifactId>reporty-ng</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
```

Here is the project site: https://github.com/cosminaru/reporty-ng/wiki/MavenPlugin

Here is the github repository: https://github.com/cosminaru/reporty-ng and the plugin repository is now here:

```
  <pluginRepository>
      <id>reporty-ng</id>
      <url>https://github.com/cosminaru/reporty-ng/raw/master/dist/maven</url>
  </pluginRepository>
```

The major differences between ant and maven are:

- maven use conventions over configuration
- ant need to be fully configured

It means that with ant you can quite easily do anything you need, but you have to write ant script to achieve what you need. On the other hand with maven make a lot of assumptions about your project structure and if your project structure is conform to those assumptions: you can do a lot of usefull jobs like building, testing, packaging, generating doc with almost nothing in your pom.xml.

One important thing to understand with maven is the concept of [life-cycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). There are 3 life-cycle defined by maven : the clean-life-cycle, the default-life-cycle and the site-life-cycle.

- clean: use it to clean any previously build product
- default: use it to build, test, package your project
- site: use it to generate documentation and reports

Each life-cycle is a succession of phases. Additionaly, each phase is bound with a plugin-goal (a plugin-goal is at some point similar to an ant target). The concept of life-cycle introduce a dependency between plugin execution (and so you don't have to specify it). For instance maven knows that it must compile the sources and the tests sources before running the tests.

In your case: you need to generate a report, so it is something that can be done during the site-lyfe-cycle. You need to generate a report based on test results, so you need to run the test prior to generate reports. To do that simply run this maven command:

`mvn clean test site:site`

This command indicate to maven to:

- cleaning any previous build product (clean life-cycle)
- running the test (default life-cycle) (maven knows that it must compile before running the tests)
- generating a site with the documentation and since you have define a reporting plugin : it will be executed during the site generation.

You will find your reports under target/site directory.

Another thing to note: the saxon dependency is a dependency of the plugin, not a project dependency so you must specify it under the `<plugin>` element:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.testng.xslt</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng-xslt-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputDir>C:/Users/windowspc/workspace/windows-project/target/testng-xslt-report</outputDir>
                <showRuntimeTotals>true</showRuntimeTotals>
                <sortTestCaseLinks>true</sortTestCaseLinks>
                <testDetailsFilter>FAIL,PASS,SKIP,CONF</testDetailsFilter>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
                  <artifactId>saxon</artifactId>
                  <version>8.7</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```